# Must be a cleaner way for this

Tags: powershell

Inside a script I have a part where I go - get-aduser and pipe it to set-aduser,
I need to replace 3 fields, im doing it 3 times:

```
     get-aduser -filter 'Name -like $name' | % {Set-aduser $_ -state $pcname }
     get-aduser -filter 'Name -like $name' | % {Set-aduser $_ -POBox $bios }
     get-aduser -filter 'Name -like $name' | % {Set-aduser $_ -Description $ip }
```

I feel really akward asking this but i couldnt find how can i make it a one liner?

Comment: You can set more than one attribute at a time by simply adding the parameter to the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet  .... `Set-aduser $_ -state $pcname -POBox $bios -Description $ip` ... and so on.

Comment: That simple :( im ashamed. thank you Olaf

Answer (score 1):

ForEach-Object is not needed here, also you can use a hashtable:

```
$hash=@{
    State=$pcname
    POBox=$bios
    Description=$ip
}

Get-ADuser -Filter "Name -like '$name'"|Set-ADuser @hash
```

Answer (score 1):

-like would be used with wildcards; if the name matches exactly:

```
Set-aduser -identity $name -state $pcname -POBox $bios -Description $ip
```